# Illustrator and serif font making

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, fonts, font-design, serif

I have started to work with font making via illustrator and have a question about serif typefaces.

Below is a serif I have started (the 'A' looking thing):

[image]

I tried playing around with the stroke width modifier tool. I also know from watching documentaries on typefaces that for the most part there are done with the pen tool around the edge of the object (in this case a letter). I was just wondering if it can be done with strokes.

Is it possible I can make the feet of my 'A' look like the one in the 'ABC' (font there is Times)? I have always wondered how to do this.

Comment: Hey Rohan and welcome to GraphicDesign! What have you tried to create this effect? What resources have you looked at? We require some minimal effort from people asking questions that ask for help with implementation

Comment: @ZachSaucier I tried playing around with the stroke width modifier tool. I also know from watching documentaries on typefaces that for the most part there are done with the  pen tool around the edge of the object (in this case a letter). I was just wondering if it can be doen with strokes, thats all

Answer (score 1):

Most typefaces are not done with strokes in that way. Certainly a design like you posted is done by creating the outlines manually. You could try a stroke for the stems and then attaching a drawn serif to the ends

Some tutorials that might help you:

Browse through this site to understand how different letters are constructed:
http://letterpunch.blogspot.se/2014/09/glyph-design-lowercase-k.html

This one is for the Glyphs software but do give you an idea of usual practices:
https://glyphsapp.com/tutorials/serif-components